# Can you use VMWare's Remote Console in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, vmware

Can you use VMWare's Remote Console in Google Chrome? The main VMWare Infrastructure Web Access works fine, but the Remote Console shows an error "The VMware Remote Console Plug-in is not installed or could not be found." Does this plugin exist?

Answer (score 7):

No not until VMware creates a plug-in for Google Chrome.